# SoftLayer - How to resolve ResourceTableIds from recently ordered services

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Starting with the Account service and calling `getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems`, you can fetch all the active Billing Items, including those just recently ordered in the current billing cycle.

Tacking on an object mask that contains `invoiceItems[createDate,hostName,domainName,resourceTableId,notes]` will allow you to fetch the associated invoice items, including the invoice line for something just recently ordered within the cycle.  This will let you get an object ID that you can pull virtual guest or bare metal details with (among other things).

However, `resourceTableId` is blank (null) for newly created services.  The other fields are filled out properly, but just the id of the system or service is missing.  Everything else created outside the billing cycle will have the resourceTableId returned.

Is there some alternative way to resolve the `resourceTableId` from the Billing Items returned by `getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there no exists an alternative  way to resolve the "resourceTableId", because this item invoice which has a null value is generated for the new order, in that moment the resources have yet to be determined or assigned (hardwareId) to item invoice.

> Updated

```
1:  {
"allowCancellationFlag": 1
"cancellationDate": null
"categoryCode": "server"
"createDate": "2016-04-05T12:48:12-03:00"
"cycleStartDate": "2016-04-05T12:48:12-03:00"
"description": "Single Intel Xeon E3-1250 v2 (4 Cores, 3.60 GHz)"
"domainName": "example.com"
"hostName": "test"
"id": 90120222
"laborFee": "0"
"laborFeeTaxRate": "0"
"lastBillDate": "2016-04-05T12:48:12-03:00"
"modifyDate": "2016-04-05T15:21:30-03:00"
"nextBillDate": "2016-05-04T02:00:00-03:00"
"oneTimeFee": "0"
"oneTimeFeeTaxRate": "0"
"orderItemId": 114652123
"parentId": null
"recurringFee": "0"
"recurringFeeTaxRate": "0"
"recurringMonths": 1
"serviceProviderId": 1
"setupFee": "0"
"setupFeeTaxRate": "0"
"invoiceItems": [1]
0:  {
"createDate": "2016-04-05T12:48:12-03:00"
"domainName": "example.com"
"hostName": "test"
"resourceTableId": null
"invoice": {
"typeCode": "NEW"
}-
}-
-
"resourceTableId": 123123
}
```

> I got this: "resourceTableId": 123123

Comment: This seems understandable for services that are still being provisioned and maybe do not yet have their own IDs, but this null status stays around a long time after service provisioning completes and the object is useable (for the entire duration of the billing cycle).

I feel like there still must be some way to start with Billing Item and fetch "Infrastructure Object" once they both have their respective IDs.

Comment: This invoice item (the first generated for the new order) will keep the "null" value, The "resourceTableId" will be set in the next invoice item. Anyway the "billingItem "returns the "resourceTableId" but I think that is not the way you want to get this.

Comment: It's sadly null in all the items returned within the billing_invoice too.

Comment: Actually, did you mean there's something in the billingItem that returns it directly?  I've only see it through the invoice items.

Comment: How did you get a resourceTableId from a Billing_Item?  I get:  `Property 'resourceTableId' not valid for 'SoftLayer_Billing_Item'. (XMLRPC::FaultException)`

Comment: resourceTableId is not a property from [SoftLayer_Billing_Item](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Billing_Item) but it is displayed in the SoftLayer_Billing_Item object when I use [SoftLayer_Account::getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems) method, did you try the rest request?

Comment: Well sure enough.  If you call it without an Object Mask, it does indeed return.  Shoe-horned in at the end out of alphabetical order like the other attributes.  Gonna pass this on to SoftLayer to see if it can be documented/fixed.

Answer (score 0):

When executing the following request:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems?objectMask=mask[invoiceItems[createDate,hostName,domainName,resourceTableId,notes,invoice.typeCode]]

Method: GET
```

We can see that when `invoice.typeCode` is `“NEW”`, the "resourceTableId" will be null. But when `invoice.typeCode` is `“RECURRING”`, the "resourceTableId" field should be different that null.

In the following reference you can find some additional information about SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice states: [SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice)

Comment: Have you managed to figure out a path to get resourceTableId from a Billing Invoice?  I feel like I've tried this route ten times already, but with no other leads I'm going to have to try this again.